# How to draw a line or curve with blurry shadow?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to do that with quartz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `CGContextSetShadow(context, offset, blur)` prior to drawing your path.

```
CGSize offset;
float blur;
offset.width = 10;
offset.height = -10;

CGContextSetShadow(context, offset, blur);
CGContextRect(context, CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Even though I could manage to draw a simple line, it won't be blurry at all.